# database access and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I am trying  to understand how the database access model works in asp.net mvc, some examples has the work in the controller but other has examples in the model.

I want to know how to do it using ado.net, the best practices is use a class in the model layer and try my database access there?

all examples are with EF and LINQ, I want to know the best way to do it using ado.net.

the database access is in model or controller?

Comment: FWIW, I've generally put data access in the _data_, as distinct from the _view_, models.  Each class knows what it needs to do to persist itself and do other useful things, e.g. Get, Save (which typically handles both add and update), Delete, GetAll, Search, ..., ToString, Parse, ... .  Some classes support both shallow and deep operations to better match the needs of applications, e.g. get an order with basic information or with full contact information, billing information, line items, shipping status, estimated lead times, ... .

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean with 'put data access in the data' I trying to understand if is a good practice get the dal access from the model or the controller.

Comment: The controller is responsible for navigation and related issues, but generally should not be responsible for direct data access.  As an example data model class, I have to handle PayPal preapproved payment agreements.  The class contains the members (UserId, EndingDate, NumberOfPayments, ...) and constructors.  It also contains methods that invoke SQL Server stored procedures to manage persisted instances (Add, Get, Cancel, Charge, Delete, ...).  The controller uses this class to support the view models, which in turn support the views.  The data model is shared among projects.

Comment: oh ok, I now understand what do you try to mean. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an architectural design to consider:

1. The Views and Controllers are in the **MVC website**.
2. The **Models** are in a separate project.
3. The **data access** code is in a third project called DataAccess or
   Repository.

The website has references to the Models and DataAccess projects. The DataAccess project also has a reference to the Models project.

This way, the data access code is separate. It is easier to find and maintain. It could be used in another solution. You could even swap it out for a completely different data access layer -- say, switching from Linq to SQL to Entity Framework or classic ADO.Net.

By keeping the Models in a separate project, they can be referenced by both the website and the data access layer. In addition, the Models project could be used in other solutions, just like the loosely-coupled data access layer.

Separating the layers this way makes it easier to add **testing**, too. That would be made easier if the data access layer/repository utilizes interfaces and dependency injection.

Comment: Many thanks, I am reading the asp.net mvc tutorials and dont have this way to work. I am new with MVC.

Comment: @NewCastle79: check out the [Contoso University tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). It puts everything in one project, but has a separate folder for the data access layer code. That folder could be migrated to a separate project, as I proposed. I think that is an excellent tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Database access should be done in the controller.  I'm not sure specifically what EF examples you've seen, but in many the EF entities themselves are the Model  (This is typically a quick and easy way to get started with a website, but isn't viable for big websites).  Basically, the controller is responsible for fetching/generating the model, which it then passes to the view.

Comment: I am reading two books and only has examples with linq and EF.

Comment: I'm not sure what approach they're taking, but from examples I've seen, the Model are the entities that you've defined in your entity framework mappings.  Your controller will generally get an instance of the EF data context and query entities based on the values passed to the controller.  The controller then pass the model object to the view to be rendered.  Model objects should contain no logic, just simple properties that the view uses to render the page.  The controller contains the data access logic.  The view contains all the rendering and display logic.

Comment: now I understand what you do trying to mean, many thanks w.brian